# Moving arrows down in tikz diagrams

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, chemistry, flow-charts

I try to create a "reaction scheme" using the tikz environment. Here is a part of the code:

```
\node (Ba2+) [compound] {\ce{Ba^{2+}}};
\node (BaSO4) [compound, right of=BaO, xshift=1cm] {\ce{BaSO4}};
\draw [arrow] (Ba2+)--node[anchor=south]{\ce{SO4^{2-}}}(BaSO4);
```

What I want to do (and don't know how) is to move the arrow vertically down. LaTeX just draws the arrow from the center of (Ba2+) to that of (BaSO4), but I want the arrow to be lower.
Using `\vspace{}` doesn't move the arrow.

Comment: I think  `chemformula` would be more relevant.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this might be a solution for you?:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
    
    normal:\\
    
    \ch[arrow-yshift=0pt]{Ba^{2+} ->[ {SO4^2-} ] BaSO4}\\
    
    lowered:\\
    
    \ch[arrow-yshift=-3pt]{Ba^{2+} ->[ {SO4^2-} ] BaSO4}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** An example which uses chemfig(which uses tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}
    
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{Ba^{2+}}
    \arrow{->[\chemfig{SO_4^{2-}}][][-3pt]}
    \chemfig{BaSO_4}
    \schemestop
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT_2:** An example of drawing vertical

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}
    
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{Ba^{2+}}
    \arrow{->[\chemfig{SO_4^{2-}}][][-3pt]}
    \chemfig{BaSO_4}
    \schemestop
    
    \schemestart
    \arrow[45]B\arrow[-20,2]C
    \schemestop\bigskip
    
    \schemestart
    \arrow[90,,thick]B\arrow[,2]C\arrow[-45,,dashed,red]D
    \schemestop
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT_3:** Example of reaction scheme with reactents in boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
    \setchemfig{compound style={draw,line width=0.8pt,semitransparent,text opacity=1,inner sep=8pt,rounded corners=1mm}} 
    
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{Ba^{2+}}
    \arrow([fill=white]--[fill=white]){->[\chemfig{SO_4^{2-}}]}[45]\chemfig{BaSO_4}
    \arrow(--[fill=white])\chemfig{BaO + SO_2}
    \arrow(--[fill=white]){-U>[*{0.180}\chemfig{O_2}]}[-90]\chemfig{BaO_2}
    \schemestop
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I intended to do. However, I need to do it under the tikzpicture environment. I'm making a much larger reaction flowchart with many reactions so using the chemformula package won't help much.

Comment: So what do you exactly want to do. Haven´t you considered Chemfig as a better option than tikz for drawing molecules etc.?

Comment: see my edit in my answer

Comment: Here is an example:

`
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

   \node (NaO2) [compound] {\ce{NaO2}};
   \node (Na) [Group 1, below of=NaO2] {\textbf{\ce{Na}}};
   \node (Na2O2) [compound, right of=Na, xshift=3cm] {\ce{Na2O2}};
   \node (NaH) [compound, left of=Na, xshift=-3cm] {\ce{NaH}};
   \node (NaHCO3) [compound, below of=NaH, xshift=-3cm]{\ce{NaHCO3}};
   \node (Na2CO3) [compound, below of=NaHCO3]{\ce{Na2CO3}};

   \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}`

Comment: How is compound defiened?

Comment: \tikzstyle{compound} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.8cm,text centered, draw=black]

Comment: The problem that I have with using the chemfig package is that some of the arrows in the "reaction scheme" will also be vertical and diagonal, so that's why I used the tikz environment

Comment: You can still do that easily in chemfig! see EDIT_2. You know Chemfig uses tikz.

Comment: @Roland On pag.36 of the ChemFig documentation is claimed that `\chemfig` can be used inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: Oh I see! Using `\chemfig` might be the solution. Do you know if there's a way to keep my definition for `compound` in `\chemfig`? (i.e. keep making the chemicals appear in the same style of box). I don't want to lose the work I did by now in tikz.

Comment: @vi pia Nobody doubts that,but I think this wasn´t the question.

Comment: @mastron9 Yes you can use your styles. I have made a third edit with a reaction sheme of what I think you want to accomplish. You can change it to your needs.